# What's a good practice to call an action from another action of the same model in mobx-state-tree?

Tags: javascript, mobx, mobx-state-tree

I am trying to wrap multiple functions inside one.

I have a model like this:

```js
const CookModel = types.actions(self =>({
  talkToSousChefs:() => {
    // talk to sous-chefs
  },
  talkToWaiters: () => {
    // business logic
  },
  talkToVendors: () => {
    // business logic
  },
  runTalkRoutine: () => {
    // current code

    const root = getRoot<typeof CookModel>(self)

    root.talkToSousChefs()
    root.talkToVendors()
    root.talkToWaiters()

    // what's the best practice?
  }
}))
```

**What's the best way to wrap those actions in `runTalkRoutine`?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That would do it but I would use `self` directly

```
  runTalkRoutine: () => {
    self.talkToSousChefs()
    self.talkToVendors()
    self.talkToWaiters()
  }
```

If any of your actions are async you can use `yield`

If you want autocomplete you can move the `runTalkRoutine` to another actions block

```
const CookModel = types.actions(self =>({
  talkToSousChefs:() => {
    // talk to sous-chefs
  },
  talkToWaiters: () => {
    // business logic
  },
  talkToVendors: () => {
    // business logic
  }
})).actions(self => ({
  runTalkRoutine: () => {
    // here you will have autocomplete on self
    self.talkToSousChefs()
    self.talkToVendors()
    self.talkToWaiters()
  }
}))
```